# Why Fiddlercore is not working when fiddler is closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, fiddler, fiddlercore

I am accessing t inside WPF application and code is like below

```
Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;        
FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.network.streaming.abortifclientaborts", true);
FiddlerCoreStartupFlags oFCSF = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;

try
{
   int iPort = 8888;
   FiddlerApplication.Startup(iPort, oFCSF);
   //FiddlerApplication.Startup(iPort, true, true, true);
   FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Created endpoint listening on port {0}", iPort);

   FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Starting with settings: [{0}]", oFCSF);
   FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Gateway: {0}", CONFIG.UpstreamGateway.ToString());
   }
   catch { }
```

What do I need to change in settings? Initial startup entries from log are as follows

> 2016-04-20 22:03:42,949 [9] INFO FiddlerCore Starting 2016-04-20
>
> 22:03:43,159 [9] INFO Created endpoint listening on port 8888
>
> 2016-04-20 22:03:43,159 [9] INFO Starting with settings: [Default]
>
> 2016-04-20 22:03:43,160 [9] INFO Gateway: System 2016-04-20
>
> 22:03:44,928 [14] INFOFiddler.Network.AutoProxy> AutoProxy Detection
>   failed. 2016-04-20 22:03:44,928 [14] INFO AutoProxy failed. Disabling
>   for this network.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by FiddlerCore developer Eric Lawrence at [Fiddler Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/3WrYJI7b4D4) , I had to create root certificates in the beginning for intercepting secure traffic. There is more to this than creating certificates though. Blog post [Understanding Fiddler certificate generators](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telerik.com%2Fblogs%2Funderstanding-fiddler-certificate-generators&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGiOdhloNdFcpIO8CUI8goHjbVJYA) explains in details as to the gotchas with each method being used.